# Как мне убрать повторения ненужного кода внутри условия?

Tags: c++

Все привет :) будьте внимательны пожалуйста

У меня в коде есть много разных условий, каждое условие уникально и имеет уникальный код.

Код который внизу создан для примера, он работает правильно!

```
            int a = 0;
            /* .... */
            if (a == 0) // здесь будет код, очень длинный, число это просто пример!!!
            {
                cout << a << "\n" << endl;
                a++; // код который постоянно повторяется a++;
            }
            if (a == 1)
            {
                cout << a << "\n" << endl;
                a++; // 
            }
            if (a == 2) {
                cout << a << "\n" << endl;
                a++;
            }
            if (a == 3) {
                cout << a << "\n" << endl;
                a++;    
            }
            // ответ получаем 1, 2, 3
```

как видите `a++;` постоянно повторяется 
Я бы хотел написать это один раз для всех условий, но не знаю как.

Этот вариант не подходит как видите он выполняется только один раз.

```
            int a = 0;
            /* .... */
            if (a == 0 ||
                a == 1 ||
                a == 2 ||
                a == 3 ||
                a == 4) {
                cout << a << "\n" << endl;
                a++;
            }
            // ответ только один это 0 а мне нужно типа такой ответ 0, 1, 2, 3 как будто каждое условия if было выполнено.
```

Comment: Если пример правилен (покрывает все условия), то почему бы просто не написать в конце `a += 5`? (5 это количество условий) / Однако, мне кажется что у вас что-то не так с самим алгоритмом (идеей решения практической задачи)

Comment: @avp Тут можно поподробней с a+=5 мне стало интересно, возможно это что то уникальное :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну сделайте проверку в отдельной функции:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto a{0};
    auto const checker
    {
        [&](auto const condition) 
        {
            if(condition)
            {
                ::std::cout << a << ::std::endl;
                a++; // код который постоянно повторяется a++;
            }
        }
    };
    checker(a == 0);
    checker(a == 1);
    checker(a == 2);
    checker(a == 3);
}
```

Вариант без лямбды:

```
struct ChainCheck
{
    int & a;
    auto operator ()(bool const condition) const
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            ::std::cout << a << ::std::endl;
            a++; // код который постоянно повторяется a++;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto a{0};
    ChainCheck{a}(a == 0)(a == 1)(a == 2)(a == 3);
}
```

Comment: Частично работает, а можно это как то оптимизировать,
например сделать без лямда функций или не использовать auto?

Comment: У меня throw 0; крашь ошибку вызывает, думаю это из за лямды

Comment: @loli А это уже оптимизировано. Можно написать то же самое без лямбды, но результат будет примерно таким же. А auto чем не угодил? "*У меня throw 0; крашь ошибку вызывает*" в моем ответе `throw 0;` нет.

Comment: Ваш код работает нормально, просто я добавляю свой код и все крашеца,
просто вместо a++ добил throw 0; можете попробовать.
А можно пример без лямда функции?

Comment: @loli "*вместо a++ добил throw 0;*" - это должно приводить к аварийному завершению приложения через вызов terminate так как исключение не перехватывается. Пример без лямбды будет практически таким же, стоит только сделать класс с одним полем - ссылкой на локальную переменную и operator ().

Comment: А как тогда быть, мне нужно использовать исключения

Comment: @loli ну так его надо потом перехватывать и обрабатывать

Comment: Все понял, надо было просто внутри лямды добавить try catch, запутался немного.
Я правильно понял что проще не сделать, ну типа красивее что бы сразу понимать что происходит?

Comment: @loli Красиво? На С++? неее….

Comment: Жалко что красиво нельзя сделать, по феншую :)

Comment: Спасибо, может я попытаюсь чет сделать используя шаблоны, но там походу нужно auto использовать а шаблоны не дают их использовать.